# How to replace a char from a string with a specified text?

Tags: javascript, string, function, replace, substring

I want to write a function in which when a string is given and it automatically replaces string with specified values.
For Example :-

```
let name = 'app';
valueReplace(name);

function valueReplace(value){
//Have to change char 'a' 'p' 'p' with the values given below 

let a = '2G8D';
let p = '7K5A';

/*
Code that will help to do this
*/

}
```

Comment: On Stackoverflow, it's usually expected that you make some amount of effort to solve the problem yourself, and then ask questions about what you're having problems with. It's not generally a place to ask people to entirely implement something for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
const p = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. If the dog reacted, was it really lazy?';

console.log(p.replace('dog', 'monkey'));
// expected output: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy monkey. If the dog reacted, was it really lazy?"


const regex = /Dog/i;
console.log(p.replace(regex, 'ferret'));
// expected output: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy ferret. If the dog reacted, was it really lazy?"
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex for this

```js
let name = 'app';
console.log(valueReplace(name));

function valueReplace(value){
//Have to change char 'a' 'p' 'p' with the values given below 
  let a = '2G8D';
  let p = '7K5A';
  return value.replace(/a/g, "2G8D").replace(/p/g, "7K5A");


}
```